# Can someone give me the code for a specific .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I tried to make my own .htaccess file with a few thing in it, but I'a not very familiar with it. I googled a lot but at the end I only managed to mess things up.
So, can someone give me working .htaccess code snippet?
I want it to do the following:

1. redirect from non-www to www
2. redirect index.php to / in all directories
3. remove ".php" from all files in all directories
4. redirect URL's like product.php?detail=Phone to product/detail/Phone
   (also manage the trailing slash problem)

Hope someone can help.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

#non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nevca.getfreehosting.co.uk [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L] 

# index.php to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]


#index/menu/123/ to index.php?menu=123
RewriteRule ^index/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?menu=$1 [L]

#index.php?menu=123 to index/menu/123/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index2\.php\?menu=([^&]+)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://example.co.uk/index/%1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php

# Forces a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Something like this, just the last 2 rules don't work...
And I also want the .php to be removed only when request is not like ".php?..."

Comment: check out this [mod-rewrite tutorial](http://www.easymodrewrite.com/guide-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

There are some of these thing in the html5 boilerplate htaccess, you should take a look and use the part you want:
http://html5boilerplate.com/